# Find random word in c++ string

Tags: c++, string

How would I pick a random word in a C++ string? Also is there a better way to handle importing the words? Just started learning C++ this week.

Current Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class WordList {
private:
  std::ifstream m_file;
  std::string m_wl;
public:
  WordList(const char* f) {
    m_file.open(f);

    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(m_file, str)) {
      m_wl += str;
      m_wl.push_back('\n');
    }
  }

  bool isWord(std::string s) {
    if (m_wl.find(s) != std::string::npos) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Generating" << std::endl;

  WordList list("sgb-words.txt");
  std::cout << list.isWord("hello") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does your file contain one word per line?  If so, why don't you use `std::vector<std::string> m_wl;`.  Your life will be so very much easier.

Comment: @paddy Yes it does, I’ll look into that

Comment: It is really good to see any question with with any effort… It was scarce in these days..

Comment: Start with reading the input into a container. The `std::vector` Paddy suggested is pretty much the go-to for this kind of work. Once you get that working, then look into random selection. [The example at the bottom of this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) shows how to generate a random number you can use to index the container.

Comment: @paddy If I have over 5k words is it still best to use a vector? That was the thing I was worried about when I was deciding if I was going to use either a array or a string.

Comment: Absolutely.  Don't forget that no matter what you do, you need to store data somewhere.  The way you initially wrote it, you'd just build one really large string.  How about you explain why you think a vector would be bad.  What exactly are you concerned about?  On desktop machines 5K words is nothing.

Comment: I guess thats true, I didn't want to use too much memory but yeah, most computers now aday have over 8gb's. Also, I'm guessing I should use a array instead of a vector since I know how much I am putting into it, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you know how much you're putting in, it's still advisable to use a vector.  Just call `.reserve` on the vector before you loop, to pre-allocate the number of things you plan to push into it.  The great thing is that if in future you exceed that amount of stuff then your program won't crash and burn in a firey mess (unlike a fixed-size array) -- it'll just extend the vector for however much it needs to hold.

Comment: @paddy Alright and one more question, should I initialize a int to 0 then in the loop use `m_wl[i++] = str`?

Comment: And in case you're still worried, let's say your program is 64-bit.  Depending on the implementation, the size of a `std::string` is generally a few pointers.  A quick test in gcc on a 64-bit system shows it is 32 bytes (4 pointers).  Now, 5k strings is about 160kB.  That's for the string class itself, but most implementations will share some of their memory to hold small strings directly instead of allocating.  Even if that's not true, then you potentially have 160kB of purely index data _plus_ your strings.  If you don't like that, build one string, then make a vector of indices into it.

Comment: @ATK no, if your vector is empty you cannot index into it like that.  Use `push_back`.  Even with `reserve` it does not create actual elements -- it only reserves memory to prevent growing the vector's storage periodically.  You can only use that index style if you used `resize` instead.

Comment: @paddy Alright, everything is now working, thanks for your help!